# Java 8 stream - Find max count values for Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am not so familiar with Java 8 and looking to see if I could find something equivalent of the below code using streams.

The below code mainly tries to look for the key which has max number of values across it and returns that key. I could not find much help anywhere on this format.

```
int max = 0;
String maxValuesString = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(max < entry.getValue().size()) {
        maxValuesString = entry.getKey();
        max = entry.getValue().size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `max` with a comparator that checks the size of the value

```
String maxValuesString = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().size()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey) 
            .orElse(null);
```

**Edit**: thanks to [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/89788773?noredirect=1) by Andreas for the clean `optional.map`

Comment: For best answer: 1) Name variable same as question. 2) Don't crash and burn if map is empty, i.e. should be same result as question (`null`).

Comment: Replace `.get().getKey()` with `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null)` to support empty map.

Comment: Thanks :) Really helpful. This is my first time here and I am so happy to see such quick response :D