# Java 8 Stream - Find greatest amount for Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

How is it possible to find max sold inside a `Map<String,List<Account>>`

```
  class Account {
     String hashId;
     String address;
     BigDecimal sold;
  }
```

I saw this discussion but I cannot modify it for my case, I have to search through all the Lists to get the greatest sold value.

[Java 8 stream - Find max count values for Map<String, List<Object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408550/java-8-stream-find-max-count-values-for-mapstring-listobject)

Comment: @lkatiforis That's the question the OP already linked to.  I'm pretty sure it doesn't answer their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the max `sold` and nothing else you could do the following:

Here I assume your `Map` is named "map" and that `sold` has a getter named `getSold`.

This will return an Optional with the max value.

```
map.values()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(listOfAccounts -> listOfAccounts.stream().map(Account::getSold))
   .max(BigDecimal::compareTo);
```

Comment: if i want to fetch the account which have the biggest sold, how can i proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.  This presumes you have a getter. It returns the account that contains the highest sold.

Given

```
Map<String, List<Account>> accounts = null;
```

The best of all values

- flatmap the values
- compare the sold values
- return with get

```
Account best =
        accounts.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Account::getSold))
                .get();
```

The best of for each key

- stream the entrySet
- map it to existing key
- then stream each list and compare values, getting the max

```
Map<String, Account> bestOfEach = accounts.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .max(Comparator
                                .comparing(Account::getSold))
                        .get()));
```